# siunitx: change multiplication symbol in scientific notation

Tags: formatting, siunitx, scientific-notation

I want to change the multiplication sign of the scientific notation of the `siunitx` package to be `\cdot` instead of `\times`, but without changing the `locale` option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `locale` option just changes the values of `exponent-product` and `output-product` (and `output-decimal-marker`). You just need to change those manually:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{8x9e11}

\num[exponent-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}]{8x9e11}

\num[output-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}]{8x9e11}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you, the exponent-product option is exactly what I needed. When using this globally by loading siunitx with this option in my case it only worked without the ensuremath, otherwise some missing }'s errors occured.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the options `exponent-product` and `output-product` globally like so:

```
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot, output-product = \cdot}
```